# Can Hunger Game winners take tesserae?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In the books, it is revealed that winners have a life of semi-luxury, never left hungry, capitols little pets. But can they take tesserae? It might be a time of general hunger or something of the sort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ability for a victor to claim Tesserae is never directly mentioned in the books or the movies. Since a victor can never be selected to participate in the Hunger Games twice (spoilers not noted here), and claiming Tesserae adds an additional chance for being selected to the reaping, I would say the answer is no. However, considering that victors receive a very large amount of income for life, they and thier family should never need the meager year's supply of grain and oil for one person that claiming Tesserae provides.

Answer (score 3):

Katniss says it herself, she is well enough off that she doesn't *need* to take take Tesserae or even go hunting; from *Catching Fire*:

> I've been in the woods three hours, but as I've made no real attempt at hunting, I have nothing to show for it. It doesn't matter for my mother and little sister, Prim, anymore. **They can afford to buy butcher meat in town**, although none of us likes it any better than fresh game. But my best friend, Gale Hawthorne, and his family will be depending on today's haul and I can't let them down.
> ...
> And here I am with buckets of money, far more than enough to feed **both** our families now, and he won't take a single coin.
> <sup>*-The Hunger Games: Catching Fire, Part One - The Spark, Chapter One*
> [emphasis mine]</sup>

**Whether or not the rules allow one to do so is not explained anywhere; [S. Fruggiero's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68586/21267) goes into the logic of why you wouldn't want or need to.**

I will add one point though:

- What will stop you from taking a million Tesserae since you are excluded from the games?

Comment: I would like a million tesserae to give out for free if I won the games. Good point! ;D

Answer (score 1):

No. They cannot take tesserae. You can only take tesserae if your name is in the box on the reaping day a number of times because that's the exchange. You get your oil and bread and get more chances of getting reaped.
Victors have their name removed from the reaping forever, therefore they cannot have tesserae.
Not that they need them to begin with.